# Google Maps JS: How do I get the small tooltip marker on hover AND the normal info window on click?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So check any google maps result like this: http://g.co/maps/htdva

If you hover over a marker, you get the tooltip.  If you click it you get the big infowindow.  I've got the infowindow working just fine via: [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example/3059129#3059129)

Here's a picture of both the mini tooltip and the infowindow:
[image]

Here is a jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3VMPL/

Answer (score 14):

Set the title property of the marker to the tooltip you want.

```
var tooltip = "some text";
marker = new google.maps.Marker({map:map, position:position, title:tooltip});
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what you are trying to do here.  Would you mind sharing a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3VMPL/

Comment: You get a box popping up on rollover on a marker with the text in it. I edited yours here http://jsfiddle.net/so1connor/APTYA

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not talking about the standard html title tooltip.  Please see the attached image in the OP... the Dairy Queen tooltip is what I'm interested in (check this link: http://g.co/maps/htdva).  After exploring google maps more, it seems that this may not be part of the maps API, but that they are implementing another tooltip js

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want can be found here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

```
// This example displays a marker at the center of Australia.
// When the user clicks the marker, an info window opens.

function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
      'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
      'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
      'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
      '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
      'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
      'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
      'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
      'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
      'Heritage Site.</p>'+
      '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
      'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
      '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of code here, since a link could go down in the future...

Comment: @Naruto sure thing I have now edited my comment with the code provided on Google's Maps Documentation :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CSS only, but be warned that it's pretty hacky and can stop working any time if Google changes its markup:

```css
.gmnoprint[title] {
  overflow: visible !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.gmnoprint[title]:after {
  content: attr(title);
  /* Style your tooltip */
}
```